# can not use unix $variable in awk command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have following variable set in my unix environment. If i try to use it in awk command its not working but the same command is working when i dont use $b variable

$b="NEW"

when i try following command **it is not working**

```
 echo "$a" | tr [a-z] [A-Z]  |awk -v RS=, '/TABLE/&&/CREATE/&&/`echo ${b}`/{print $NF}'
```

But, if i replace the $b value to NEW as **below its working**

```
 echo "$a" | tr [a-z] [A-Z]  |awk -v RS=, '/TABLE/&&/CREATE/&&/NEW/{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use a `bash` var inside `awk` like that. Instead, use:

```
echo "$a" | tr [a-z] [A-Z] | awk -v RS=, -v myvar=$b '/TABLE/&&/CREATE/&& $0~myvar {print $NF}'
```

See an example:

```
$ var="hello"
$ awk -v text=$var 'BEGIN{print text}'
hello
```

Also, to me it works with `tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'` instead of `tr [a-z] [A-Z]`. And based on [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100028/can-not-use-unix-variable-in-awk-command/22100063#comment33522254_22100063) suggestion, you can skip it by using the `IGNORECASE = 1`:

```
echo "$a" | awk -v RS=, -v myvar=$b 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} /TABLE/&&/CREATE/&& $0~myvar {print $NF}'
```

Comment: Agreed, regarding the `tr`, In fact, it may be more elegant to set IGNORECASE=1 in the awk script.

Comment: That's a really good point, @MarkSetchell If you don't mind I will add it to my answer, for completeness. Thanks!

Comment: @fedorqui : if the $b has '_' its not working

Comment: @logan please update your question with sample input and desired output. Otherwise we are so abstract to give real answers.

Comment: @fedorqui : `awk -v myvar=$b -F'$0~myvar' '{print $2}'` is this correct method of using ?

Comment: @logan no. `-F` is set to give values to separate the fields, not for regex. As I said, update your question with proper input and desired output.

Comment: @logan You need to read this [book](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gnu.org%2Fs%2Fgawk%2Fmanual%2Fgawk.pdf&ei=Q7wQU5bUIsT0kQef2YCwCQ&usg=AFQjCNEFmuFZDNP61UcJ5jX1yUSxiy2AUw&sig2=A1U46Gd1UiM3fZpisXLOyA&bvm=bv.61965928,d.eW0).

Comment: @fedorqui : my question is not changed. `my another requirement is, i need to use $b in -F statement`

Comment: @logan you did not ask for that in the beginning. Instead of asking more questions in comments, also repeating them in every answer, do  [Ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). It will be more clear what you want and people will appreciate not having to update the answer over and over again.

Comment: @fedorqui : i raised it . please have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101034/can-not-use-unix-variable-in-fiexd-search-of-awk-command

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question:

```
if i replace the $b value to NEW as below its working
```

It works because the value of your variable is `NEW` and what you end up doing is using that in the `regex`, which is exactly how it is supposed to be done.

about your second question:

```
can not use unix $variable in awk command
```

You cannot use `shell` variables in `awk` like that. You need to create an `awk` variable by using `-v` option and assigning your `bash` variable.

```
awk -v awkvar="$bashvar" '/ /{ ... }'
```

This makes your existing syntax as:

```
echo "$a" | tr [a-z] [A-Z]  | awk -v RS=, -v var="$b" '/TABLE/&&/CREATE/&&/var/{print $NF}'
```

This again won't work because inside `/../` variables are not interpolated, meaning they are considered literally. So, you need to do:

```
echo "$a" | tr [a-z] [A-Z]  |awk -v RS=, -v var="$b" '/TABLE/&&/CREATE/&&$0~var{print $NF}'
```

Comment: if the $b has '_' its not working

Comment: @logan Define not working? Error? No Output?

Comment: `awk -v myvar=$b -F'$0~myvar' '{print $2}'` is this correct method of using ?