# can not use unix $variable in Fixed search of awk command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I can not use unix $variable in Fiexd search of awk command.

Please see below my commands.

```
a="NEW_TABLES NEW_INSERT"
b="NEW"
echo $a | awk -v myvar=$b -F'$0~myvar' '{print $2}'
```

is not returning any output

but if manually enter the $b value there , its working as below

```
echo $a | awk -v -F'NEW' '{print $2}'

    outputs: 
 TABLES NEW_INSERT
```

Comment: @downvoter: Explain the reason

Comment: I didn't downvote... Also, it would be good to give a sample of what's in the `$a` variable.

Comment: @fedorqui: it contains NEW_TABLES
NEW_INSERT

Comment: OK, just updated to show it.

Comment: me too updated the question. pls provide the answer

Comment: your use of awk is somewhat unorthodox.  it would be better if you *showed* inputs explained what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Also it would be important to indicate what is your expected output.

Comment: I believe it is important to post what i have tried. so i have posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should make it:

```
$ a="NEW_TABLES NEW_INSERT"

$ echo $a | awk -F"NEW_" '{print $2}'
TABLES 

$ b="NEW_"
$ echo $a | awk -F"$b" '{print $2}'
TABLES
```

Comment: if i use semi colon ';' in the awk it throws error.

`awk -F'\;' '{print $1}'` Output : 

`awk: warning: escape sequence \;' treated as plain ;'`

Comment: No need to escape the `;`. Use directly `awk -F';'`

Answer (score 1):

Your quotings are all messed up and you can use your variable to split the line using split function:

```
a="NEW_TABLES NEW_INSERT"
b="NEW"
echo $a | awk -v myvar="$b" '{split($0,ary,myvar);print ary[2]}'
```

**Outputs:**

```
_TABLES
```